# Komodo 8.5: PHP 'block' and 'inline' snippets do not work where needed

Tags: php, komodo-ide

I've just started using Komodo IDE 8.5.4 for editing a PHP project and want to use snippets to quickly type in the PHP start and end tags.

The `block` snippet *does* produce this:

```
<?php


 ?>
```

and the `inline` snippet *does* produce this:

```
<?php echo $var; ?>
```

The problem is these only seem to work *when used within a PHP code block and not when outside one* - which is precisely the opposite of how it should be.

Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out your toolbox (View > Tabs & Sidebars > Toolbox), you can move these snippets around there in your Abbreviations folder. Note that these are sample snippets meant for people to get started with, so please make sure you move your Abbreviations folder outside of the "Samples" folder if you intend to use it.

Also note that you can use a snippet anywhere you want, its only the auto-abbreviation part that limits it by language. You could also insert the snippet with the "Invoke" tool (Ctrl+Shift+I).